# How waitpid is better than wait when multiple SIGCHLDs are raised simultaneously?

Tags: sockets, unix, wait, waitpid, sigchld

In the book "Unix network programming, Volume 1" by Richard Stevens, in the section "Difference between wait vs waitpid", it says waitpid() should be used intead of wait(). I understand the problem described when using wait(). It says, when multiple child processes terminate simultaneously and hence multiple SIGCHLDs are raised, the parent may get delivered only the first of them and the others would be lost since the kernel does not queue signals. Ok, but how does waitpid avoid this problem ?

Below is how the book uses waitpid() in the signal handler:

```
    while ( (pid = waitpid(-1, &stat, WNOHANG) ) > 0) {
        printf("child %d terminated\n", pid);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty is that a signal `SIGCHLD` only tells that *at least* one child process has exited or changed its state. You don't know how many `wait` or `waitpid` calls are required.

According to the documentation, e.g. https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid or https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html, a call

```
pid_t pid = wait(&status);
```

is equivalent to

```
pid_t pid = waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
```

Your example

```
while ( (pid = waitpid(-1, &stat, WNOHANG) ) > 0) {
    printf("child %d terminated\n", pid);
}
```

uses the additional flag `WNOHANG`, which makes the call non-blocking. This means you can repeatedly call `waitpid` in a loop until it tells you that it has not found any more process. So you can wait for as many processes as have exited now without knowing their number. After exiting from the loop, the parent process can continue its normal processing.

In contrast to this, `wait` would block if there is still a running child process that has not exited or changed its state yet. This would happen when you call `wait` in a similar loop. There is no option to make `wait` non-blocking in this case. (You could interrupt it by a signal, though.)

So `waitpid` does not avoid the problem but allows you to handle it without blocking your parent process. It depends on your program if the non-blocking `waitpid` is useful or required, or if a possibly blocking `wait` is sufficient.

Comment: hmm, It's true that a non-blocking version of wait is required in a TCP server. So, for now, it seems "the multiple simultaneous SIGCHLDs" problem applies even to waitpid, unless someone provides us with another explanation for that.

Comment: @Jayanth This is what meant with the last paragraph. Using `waitpid` does not change the behavior of the signals. You can still get less signals than exited processes, but you can call `waitpid` in a loop without blocking to "wait" for more than process if necessary.